# Understanding NFS

Tags: filesystems

HI

I would like to understand the NFS filesystem in some detail. I came across the book NFS illustrated, unfortunately it is only available as google books so some pages are missing.
Has someone maybe another good ressource which would be a good start to understand NFS at a low level? I am thinking of implementing a Client/Server Framework

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is documentation how NFS implemented in the Linux kernel

http://nfs.sourceforge.net/

Other resources are RFC documents

http://tools.ietf.org/

Answer (score 3):

*NFS Illustrated* is available in dead-tree form - amazon have it in stock (as of a minute ago). The 'Illustrated series are generally pretty good and while I haven't read the NFS one I've got good info from others in the series. If you're considering implementing a full client/server framework for it then it might be worth the money.

Comment: What do you mean by dead-tree form?

Answer (score 1):

As my current field of work is on NFS, I really think you may build some knowledge first on:

1. Red Hat NFS related Documents:
   https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-nfs.html
2. Microsoft NFS related Documents:
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302(v=ws.10).aspx

After you understand the unmapped structure among AD and Unix(It really took me a long period of time), you may get to build some knowledge on `sec=krb /krb5i /krb5p` by the MIT`s Original Documents ,these are the core of the NFS.